# adding an apostrophe to submitted variable into database

Tags: php, mysql

I have been struggling with this code. I am not able to add a name like O'Brian. When using an apostrophe I am receiving the error "Error updating Team details: You have an error in your SQL syntax;" When I take the apostrophe out of the form, it runs ok. Where am I failing?

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])): 
$TeamName = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['TeamName']); 

$sql = "UPDATE Team SET TeamName = 'TeamName'  WHERE id ='$id'";

else:

$id = $_GET['id']; 

$EditTeam=@mysql_query("SELECT *
                      FROM Team 
                      WHERE ID='$id'"); 
if (!$EditTeam) { 
die('<p>Error fetching Team details: ' . 
    mysql_error() . '</p>'); 
} 

$Team = mysql_fetch_array($EditTeam); 

$TeamName =  stripslashes($Team['TeamName']);
```

---

Here is the entire code!

```
<head>
<title>Update Contact Info</title>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var newWindow = null; 

function closeWin(){ 
if (newWindow != null){ 
if(!newWindow.closed) 
newWindow.close(); 
} 
} 

function popUpWin(url, type, strWidth, strHeight){ 

closeWin(); 

if (type == "fullScreen"){ 

strWidth = screen.availWidth - 10; 
strHeight = screen.availHeight - 160; 
} 

var tools=""; 
if (type == "standard" || type == "fullScreen") tools = "resizable,toolbar=yes,location=yes,scrollbars=yes,menubar=yes,width="+strWidth+",height="+str    Height+",top=0,left=0"; 
if (type == "console") tools = "resizable,toolbar=no,location=no,scrollbars=yes,width="+strWidth+",height="+strHeight+",left=    0,top=0"; 
newWindow = window.open(url, 'newWin', tools); 
newWindow.focus(); 
} 
</script> 
</head>
<body alink="#0033FF"  link="#0033FF" vlink="#0033FF">
<center>
<?php include 'memberheader_b_ball.php';?>
</center>

<?php
$ID = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']); 


if (isset($_POST['submit'])): 
// The team's details have 
// been updated. 


$TeamName = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['TeamName']); 
$ID = $_POST['id'];
$teamage = $_POST['teamage'];
$teamcity = $_POST['teamcity'];
$teamstate = $_POST['teamstate'];
$division = $_POST['division'];
$contactname = $_POST['contactname'];
$contactlname = $_POST['contactlname'];
$contactaddressmore = $_POST['contactaddressmore'];
$contactaddress = $_POST['contactaddress'];
$contactcity = $_POST['contactcity'];
$contactstate = $_POST['contactstate'];
$contactcountry = $_POST['contactcountry'];
$contactzip = $_POST['contactzip'];
$contactphone = $_POST['contactphone'];
$contactcphone = $_POST['contactcphone'];
$contactfax = $_POST['contactfax'];
$contactemail = $_POST['contactemail'];
$coachname = $_POST['coachname'];
$coachlname = $_POST['coachlname'];
$coachaddress = $_POST['coachaddress'];
$coachcity = $_POST['coachcity'];
$coachstate = $_POST['coachstate'];
$coachzip = $_POST['coachzip'];
$coachsphone = $_POST['coachphone'];
$coachfax = $_POST['coachfax'];
$coachemail = $_POST['coachemail'];


$sql = "UPDATE Team SET 

      TeamName = 'TeamName',
              teamage='$teamage',
      teamcity='$teamcity',
      teamstate='$teamstate',
      division='$division',
      contactname='$contactname',
      contactlname='$contactlname',
      contactaddress='$contactaddress',
      contactaddressmore='$contactaddressmore',
      contactcity='$contactcity',
      contactcountry='$contactcountry',
      contactstate='$contactstate',
      contactzip='$contactzip',
      contactphone='$contactphone',
      contactcphone='$contactcphone',
      contactfax='$contactfax',
      coachname='$coachname',         
      coachlname='$coachlname',
      coachaddress='$coachaddress',
      coachcity='$coachcity',
      coachstate='$coachstate',
      coachzip='$coachzip',
      coachphone='$coachphone',
      coachfax='$coachfax',
      coachemail='$coachemail'
      WHERE id ='$ID'"; 



if (mysql_query($sql)) { 
echo("<div align='center'>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>

<p><font size='6' face='Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif'><ul><strong>Processing your request, one moment.</strong></font><br>
<img src=\"images/animated_timer_bar.gif\" width=\"220\" height=\"18\"></p></div> 
<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"1;URL=editcontact.php?id=$id\">");      

} else { 
die('<p>Error updating Team details: ' . mysql_error() . '</p>'); 
}

?>
<p> 
<?php
else: // Allow the user to edit the Team 
  // with ID=$id 

//$ID = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']); 

$EditTeam=@mysql_query("SELECT *
                      FROM Team 
                      WHERE ID='$id'"); 
if (!$EditTeam) { 
die('<p>Error fetching Team details: ' . 
    mysql_error() . '</p>'); 
} 

$Team = mysql_fetch_array($EditTeam); 

$TeamName =  stripslashes($Team['TeamName']); 
$id = $Team['ID'];
$teamage = $Team['teamage'];
$teamcity = $Team['teamcity'];
$teamstate = $Team['teamstate'];
$division = $Team['division'];
$contactname = $Team['contactname'];
$contactlname = $Team['contactlname'];
$contactaddress = $Team['contactaddress'];
$contactaddressmore = $Team['contactaddressmore'];
$contactcountry = $Team['contactcountry'];
$contactcity = $Team['contactcity'];
$contactstate = $Team['contactstate'];
$contactzip = $Team['contactzip'];
$contactphone = $Team['contactphone'];
$contactcphone = $Team['contactcphone'];
$contactfax = $Team['contactfax'];
$contactemail = $Team['contactemail'];
$coachname = $Team['coachname'];
$coachlname = $Team['coachlname'];  
$coachaddress = $Team['coachaddress'];
$coachcity = $Team['coachcity'];
$coachstate = $Team['coachstate'];
$coachzip = $Team['coachzip'];
$coachphone = $Team['coachphone'];
$coachfax = $Team['coachfax'];
$coachemail = $Team['coachemail'];
$notes = $Team['notes'];
$wait1 = $Team['wait1'];
$wait2 = $Team['wait2'];
$wait3 = $Team['wait3'];
$wait4 = $Team['wait4'];
$wait5 = $Team['wait5'];




// Convert HTML special characters 
// in database value for use in 
// an HTML document. 
$contactemail = htmlspecialchars($contactemail);
$coachemail = htmlspecialchars($coachemail);

$EditGames=@mysql_query("SELECT *
                      FROM Games 
                      WHERE GID='1'"); //GID = Games ID
if (!$EditGames) { 
die('<p>Error fetching Team details: ' . 
    mysql_error() . '</p>'); 
} 

$Games = mysql_fetch_array($EditGames); 

$tourney1date = $Games['tourney1date']; 
$tourney2date = $Games['tourney2date']; 
$tourney3date = $Games['tourney3date']; 
$tourney4date = $Games['tourney4date']; 
$tourney5date = $Games['tourney5date']; 
$tourney1name = $Games['tourney1name']; 
$tourney2name = $Games['tourney2name']; 
$tourney3name = $Games['tourney3name']; 
$tourney4name = $Games['tourney4name']; 
$tourney5name = $Games['tourney5name']; 
$tourney1city = $Games['tourney1city']; 
$tourney2city = $Games['tourney2city']; 
$tourney3city = $Games['tourney3city']; 
$tourney4city = $Games['tourney4city']; 
$tourney5city = $Games['tourney5city'];   

if ($notes == '') {
$message = '';
} else {
$message = 'You have a message! Click to read it';
}
if ($wait1 == 'yes') {
$pay1 = 'Print a personal <a href="paymentform1.php?id=';        
$id1 = $Team['ID'];
$end1 = '">'. $tourney1name .'</a> payment form.<br>';}

if ($wait2 == 'yes') {
$pay2 = 'Print a personal <a href="paymentform2.php?id=';        
$id2 = $Team['ID'];
$end2 = '">'. $tourney2name .'</a> payment form.<br>';}

if ($wait3 == 'yes') {
$pay3 = 'Print a personal <a href="paymentform3.php?id=';        
$id3 = $Team['ID'];
$end3 = '">'. $tourney3name .'</a> payment form.<br>';}

if ($wait4 == 'yes') {
$pay4 = 'Print a personal <a href="paymentform4.php?id=';        
$id4 = $Team['ID'];
$end4 = '">'. $tourney4name .'</a> payment form.<br>';}

if ($wait5 == 'yes') {
$pay5 = 'Print a personal <a href="paymentform5.php?id=';        
$id5 = $Team['ID'];
$end5 = '">'. $tourney5name .'</a> payment form.<br>';}




?>
<font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">
<?
$var =  mysql_real_escape_string("O'Brian");
echo $var;

$var = stripslashes($var);
echo $var;
?> </font>
<form action= "editcontact.php?id=<?=$ID?>" method="post">
<font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?=$ID?>" />
<div align="center">
<table width="80%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
  <tr> 
    <td width="15%"><div align="left"><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"> 
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save Changes" />
        </font> </div></td>
   <td width="85%"><div align="right">
        <table width="387">
          <tr> 
            <td width="379">&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
        </table>

      </div>
   </td>
  </tr>
</table>

</div>
</font> <font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">
<hr align="center" width="80%" />
</font> 
<center>
<table width="80%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
  <tr> 
    <td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><strong>Select division 
      for team.</strong> <br />
      </font> <table width="98%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
        <tr> 
          <td width="11%"><div align="center"><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><strong>8U</strong> 
              <input type="radio" name="division" value="8U"<?php if ($division == "8U") echo ("checked");?> />
              </font></div></td>
          <td width="11%"><div align="center"><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><strong>10U</strong> 
              <input type="radio" name="division" value="10U"<?php if ($division == "10U") echo ("checked");?> />
              </font></div></td>
          <td width="11%"><div align="center"><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><strong>12U</strong> 
              <input type="radio" name="division" value="12U"<?php if ($division == "12U") echo ("checked");?> />
              </font></div></td>
          <td width="12%"><div align="center"><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><strong>14U</strong><br />
              <input type="radio" name="division" value="14U"<?php if ($division == "14U") echo ("checked");?> />
              </font></div></td>
          <td width="12%"><div align="center"><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><strong>16U<br />
              </strong> 
              <input type="radio" name="division" value="16U"<?php if ($division == "16U") echo ("checked");?> />
              </font></div></td>
          <td width="17%"><div align="center"><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><strong>18U<br />
              </strong> 
              <input type="radio" name="division" value="18U"<?php if ($division == "18U") echo ("checked");?> />
              </font></div></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <center>
      </center></td>
    <td width="33%"><div align="center"><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><strong>      <a href="notes.php?id=<?=$ID?>" onclick="popUpWin(this.href,'console',400,350);return false;" onkeypress="popUpWin(this.href,'console',400,350);return false;" title="Link open's in a new window"> 
        <?php if ($notes == '') {  $message = '';} else { $message = 'You have a message! 
    <br /> Click to read it';} 
     print $message ?>
        </a></strong></font></div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">
<hr align="center" width="80%">
</font> 
<table width="91%" border="0">
  <tr> 
    <td height="27" colspan="3"><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><strong>Team 
      Name, Contact and Head Coach info</strong></font> </td>
    <td> <div align="right"><font size="-1" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Team 
        Age </font> </div>
    <td colspan="2"><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"> 
      <select name="teamage" size="1">
        <option value= "">Pick Age</option>
        <option value='10U'<?php if ($teamage == "10U") echo ("selected");?>>10U</option>
        <option value='12U'<?php if ($teamage == "12U") echo ("selected");?>>12U</option>
        <option value='14U'<?php if ($teamage == "14U") echo ("selected");?>>14U</option>
        <option value='16U'<?php if ($teamage == "16U") echo ("selected");?>>16U</option>
        <option value='18U'<?php if ($teamage == "18U") echo ("selected");?>>18U</option>
        <option value='18Gold'<?php if ($teamage == "18Gold") echo ("selected");?>>18Gold</option>
      </select>
      </font></td>
  </tr>
  <tr> 
    <td width="12%" height="29"><div align="right"><font size="-1" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Team 
        Name</font></div></td>
    <td colspan="2"><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"> 
      <input name="TeamName" type="text" value="<?=$TeamName?>" size="30">
      </font></td>
    <td width="10%"> <div align="right"><font size="-1" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Team 
        Location </font> </div>
    <td colspan="2"> <font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"> 
      <input name="teamcity" type="text"  value="<?=$teamcity?>" size="15" />
      <font size="-1">State</font> 
      <input name="teamstate" type="text"  value="<?=$teamstate?>" size="2" />
      </font></td>
  </tr>
  <tr> 
    <td><div align="right"><font size="-1"><font size="-1"></font></font></div></td>
    <td width="18%"><div align="left"><font size="-2" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">First 
        Name </font></div></td>
    <td width="22%"><font size="-2" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Last 
      Name </font></td>
    <td><div align="right"><font size="-1"><font size="-1"></font></font></div></td>
    <td width="17%"><div align="left"><font size="-2" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">First 
        Name </font></div></td>
    <td width="25%"><font size="-2" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Last 
      Name </font></td>
  </tr>
  <tr> 
    <td><div align="right"><font size="-1" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Contact 
        </font></div></td>
    <td colspan="2"><input name="contactname" type="text" value="<?=$contactname?>" size="20" /> 
      <input name="contactlname" type="text" id="contactlname" value="<?=$contactlname?>" size="20" /></td>
    <td><div align="right"><font size="-1" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Head 
        Coach</font></div></td>
    <td colspan="2"><input name="coachname" type="text" value="<?=$coachname?>" size="20" /> 
      <input name="coachlname" type="text" id="coachlname" value="<?=$coachlname?>" size="20" /> 
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr> 
    <td><div align="right"><font size="-1" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Address 
        </font></div></td>
    <td colspan="2"><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"> 
      <input name="contactaddress" type="text" value="<?=$contactaddress?>" size="30">
      </font></td>
    <td><div align="right"><font size="-1" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Address</font></div></td>
    <td colspan="2"><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"> 
      <input name="coachaddress" type="text" value="<?=$coachaddress?>" size="30">
      </font></td>
    </tr>
    <tr> 
    <td><div align="right"><font size="-1" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">More 
        add. </font></div></td>
    <td colspan="2"><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"> 
      <input name="contactaddressmore" type="text" value="<?=$contactaddressmore?>" size="15" />
      </font></td>
    <td><div align="right"><font size="-1" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">City</font></div></td>
    <td colspan="2"><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"> 
      <input name="coachcity" type="text" value="<?=$coachcity?>" size="15">
      <font size="-1">State</font> 
      <input name="coachstate" type="text" value="<?=$coachstate?>" size="2">
      <font size="-1">Zip</font> 
      <input name="coachzip" type="text" value="<?=$coachzip?>" size="4">
      </font></td>
  </tr>
  <tr> 
    <td><div align="right"><font size="-1" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Country</font></div></td>
    <td colspan="2"><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"> 
      <input name="contactcountry" type="text" id="contactcountry" value="<?=$contactcountry?>" size="15" />
      </font></td>
    <td><div align="right"><font size="-1" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Phone</font></div></td>
    <td colspan="2"><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"> 
      <input name="coachphone" type="text" value="<?=$coachphone?>" size="12" />
      <font size="-1">Fax</font> 
      <input name="coachfax" type="text" value="<?=$coachfax?>" size="12" />
      </font></td>
  </tr>
  <tr> 
    <td><div align="right"><font size="-1" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">City</font></div></td>
    <td colspan="2"><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"> 
      <input name="contactcity" type="text" value="<?=$contactcity?>" size="15">
      <font size="-1">State</font> 
      <input name="contactstate" type="text" value="<?=$contactstate?>" size="2">
      <font size="-1">Zip</font> 
      <input name="contactzip" type="text" value="<?=$contactzip?>" size="4">
      </font></td>
    <td><div align="right"><font size="-1" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Email</font></div></td>
    <td colspan="2"><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"> 
      <input name="coachemail" type="text" value="<?=$coachemail?>" size="30" />
      </font></td>
  </tr>
  <tr> 
    <td><div align="right"><font size="-1" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Phone</font></div></td>
    <td colspan="2"><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"> 
      <input name="contactphone" type="text" value="<?=$contactphone?>" size="12">
      <font size="-1">Fax</font> 
      <input name="contactfax" type="text" value="<?=$contactfax?>" size="12">
      </font></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr> 
    <td><div align="right"><font size="-1" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Cell 
        Phone</font></div></td>
    <td colspan="2"><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"> 
      <input name="contactcphone" type="text" value="<?=$contactcphone?>" size="12">
      </font></td>
    <td><font size="-1">&nbsp;</font></td>
    <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr> 
    <td><div align="right"><font size="-1" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Email</font></div></td>
    <td colspan="2"><div align="center"><font size="-2" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">This 
        is your registered email address.</font><br />
        <font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><? echo $contactemail; ?> 
        </font><font size="-2" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><br />
        If this is no longer a valid email, contact system admin.</font></div></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</center>
<hr align="center" width="80%">
<font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><br>
</font>
<p></p>
</form>

<?php endif;?>
</font> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That line of SQL will just update whichever to "TeamName". Please copy and paste the actual code you're using.

Comment: That above is the code I am using less the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `mysql_real_escape_string` on the `$id` value before using it in the query.

Even better, stop using `ext/mysql` and switch to `PDO`/`mysqli` and use parameterized queries, which will also escape your data properly.

Comment: I added   $id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']); 
but the same error occurs

Comment: Did you do it before `UPDATE`?  Because I see you use `$_GET` before `SELECT`

Comment: the error is Error updating Team details: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'emo', 

The string is D'emo 

I added $id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']); above if (isset but the same error occurs

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
   $sql = "UPDATE Team SET TeamName = '$TeamName'  WHERE id ='$id'";
```

try

```
 $sql = "UPDATE Team SET TeamName = \"$TeamName\"  WHERE id ='$id'";
```

Comment: Changed '$TeamName' to \"$TeamName\" no change, same error.
Remember it is only when a comma is added to the TeamName field, example Demo works and D'emo fails

Comment: i am sorry not a comma but an apostrophe